# Importing Bootstrap SCSS into a Django project

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

My question relates to the [latest Bootstrap 4.x release (beta)](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/download/)

I import the CSS from the CDN via

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Do I assume correctly, that in my custom SCSS, I can not access the variables of Bootstrap (because it's a compiled CSS, not an SCSS)? I tried to change `$spacer: 1rem !default;` and it didn't work.

Comment: please ask only one question per topic in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS has no variables, they exist in SCSS. These variables are substituted with their values during compilation. So yes, you need to download Bootstrap's SCSS sources and compile them alongside with your own SCSS files.

A common way of accomplishing it is to use [webpack](https://webpack.github.io) - regardless of your backend technology. It is a tool based on node.js (so you will have to install it as well) that allows you to manage your static assets, including installation of JS and CSS libs; ES6 to ES5, LESS and SCSS to CSS compilation; bundling; minification and so on.

Each activity usually requires a plugin. It's actually rather difficult to get webpack working as desired for the first time, but it is a common web development tool that is worth learning. You can configure webpack both to download and to compile bootstrap.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I currently solve the compilation via [django-compressor](https://github.com/django-compressor/django-compressor)

Answer (score 0):

1. **QUESTION 1**

   Your assumption is correct that the SCSS is compiled into CSS before being rendered by the browser. You should keep in mind that SCSS (or SASS) is a CSS pre-processor and cannot be rendered by the browser directly. For this, we have separate compilers in order to convert SCSS into CSS.
2. **QUESTION 2**

   You can copy this cloned SCSS files from the Git to your static folder and then you need to compile it into CSS via front-end automation tools like:

   - npm
   - Grunt
   - Gulp
   - Webpack

Comment: So then the way to go is a git clone once I navigated into the folder? I assumed there would be a sort of gemfile or any other script to be executed in the root folder that would do something like this.